# Palantir foundry code workbook, export individual xmls from dataset

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I have a dataset which have an xml column and i am trying to export individual xmls as files with filename being in another column using codeworkbook

[image]

I filtered the rows i want using below code

```
def prepare_input(xml_with_debug):
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    filter_column = "key"
    filter_value = "test_key"
    df_filtered = xml_with_debug.filter(filter_value == F.col(filter_column))

    approx_number_of_rows = 1
    sample_percent = float(approx_number_of_rows) / df_filtered.count()

    df_sampled = df_filtered.sample(False, sample_percent, seed=0)

    important_columns = ["key", "xml"]

    return df_sampled.select([F.col(c).cast(F.StringType()).alias(c) for c in important_columns])
```

It works till here. Now for the last part i tried this in a python task, but was complaining about the parameters (i should have set it up wrongly). But even if it works it will be as a single file i [think](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-repositories/prepare-datasets-download/#access-the-file-for-download).

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
@transform(
     output=Output("/path/to/python_csv"),
     my_input=Input("/path/to/input")
)
def my_compute_function(output, my_input):
     output.write_dataframe(my_input.dataframe().coalesce(1), output_format="csv", options={"header": "true"})
```

I am trying to set it up in GUI like below

[image]

My question i guess is, what will be the code in the last Python task (write_file) after the prepare input so that i extract individual xmls (And if possible zip them into single file for download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the output dataset filesystem and write files into it in whatever format you want. 
The documentation for that can be found here: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/transforms-unstructured/#writing-files 
(If you want to do it from a code repository it's very similar https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unstructured-files/#writing-files)

By doing that you can create multiple different files or you can create a single zip file and write it into a dataset.